# How come I am getting an parsing XML declaration error?

Tags: xml, google-chrome, browser

The Chrome browser error I am getting reads

```
error on line 1 at column 35: parsing XML declaration: '?>' expected
```

I dont know why it says `'?>' expected` when it is clearly there. Look at my code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<people>
    <work>
        <george height="5 11" weight="320" hairColor="No Hair">
            <address>123 Anywhere Street</address>
            <carType>No Car</carType>
            <phone>18001116585</phone>
            <favFood>Anything and Everything</favFood>
        </george>
        <paul height="5 5" weight="120" hairColor="Brown">                   
            <address>11 Sendai Street</address>
            <carType>Ford</carType>
            <phone>19731352675</phone>
            <favFood>Pizza</favFood>
        </paul>
        <jen height="5 2" weight="100" hairColor="Auburn">
            <address>94 Frelo Way</address>
            <carType>Lexus</carType>
            <phone>18981456545</phone>
            <favFood>Sushi</favFood>
        </jen>
    </work>
    <home>
    </home>
</people>
```

Thank you for your solutions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`encoding="UTF-8"` must appear before `standalone="yes"`.

The [spec says](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-XMLDecl)

> ```
>  XMLDecl    ::=      '<?xml' VersionInfo EncodingDecl? SDDecl? S? '?>'
> ```

Order is significant.

Comment: Thanks a lot. These bad tutorials! They're littering the net!

Answer (score 2):

The order of the attributes should be version, encoding, standalone.